# Compensating for the lack of 'out' parameters in async methods.

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I have a class that handles all API transactions in the application I'm working on. The general outline for its methods look like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> APICall(int bla)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            bool res;

            // Post/GetAsync to server depending on call + other logic
            return res;
        }
```

What I want to do is to be able to also return the response.StatusCode to the caller, but since we are not allowed to use 'out' parameters with async methods it complicates things a bit.

I was thinking about returning a tuple containing both the bool and the response code, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not return the `HttpResponseMessage`?

Comment: @Trickery Because there is some logic done (parsing jason etc) that I want to contain in the method.

Comment: If you are returning the StatusCode of the HTTP Response, why do you need the boolean? What purpose does it serve once you return a code that indicates if the request succeeded or not?

Comment: @Trickery Because the status code will indicate why the bool is a certain value. Al tough in most calls I'm happy just reading the bool, for login etc I might want to see if it returned false because device is blacklisted or because user is blacklisted etc (indicated by status code).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I was thinking about returning a tuple containing both the bool and the response code, is there a better way to do this?

You could create a specific class to hold the results. Personally I don't really like tuples, because names like `Item1` or `Item2` say nothing about the values.

```
class APICallResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
}

    public static async Task<APICallResult> APICall(int bla)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        bool res;

        // Post/GetAsync to server depending on call + other logic
        return new APICallResult { Success = res, StatusCode = response.StatusCode };
    }
```

Comment: +1. Tuples are horrible. They save nothing about the information which is returned.

Comment: +1 Tupples are not horrible, but should be used in the correct places. Instead of a private class in a linq chain for instance. Not as part of a public interface.

Comment: Thankfully C# 7 has introduced real, language-level tuples (with names and everything). NOW they are finally fantastic!

Answer (score 8):

Use a `Tuple<x, y>` to return more than a value. For example, to return an int and a string:

```
return Tuple.Create(5, "Hello");
```

and the type is `Tuple<int, string>`

Or you could simulate the `out`/`ref` with an array... If you pass the method an array of one element, it's like passing a `ref` or an `out` (depending on who should fill the element):

```
MyMethod(new int[1] { 6 });

void MyMethod(int[] fakeArray)
{
    if (fakeArray == null || fakeArray.Length != 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("fakeArray");
    }

    // as a `ref`
    fakeArray[0] = fakeArray[0] + 1;

    // as an `out`
    fakeArray[0] = 10;
}
```

Or using complex objects...

```
class MyReturn
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

MyMethod(new MyReturn());

void MyMethod(MyReturn ret)
{
    ret.Text = "Hello";
    ret.Value = 10;
}
```

Done...